# MySql Commandstring is switching Values with Columns

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I got a Problem with a little DB Program im working on. The Program is switching Columns with Values und i cant help myself anymore.

This is my String :

```
string dataString = "INSERT INTO kontakte(ID, Name) VALUES("+client.ID+ "," +client.Name+")"
```

Which i pass to the MySqlCommand with :

`MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(dataString, connection);`

**Funny thing now, this is what i get when i try tu run the Program :**

**INSERT INTO kontakte(ID, Name) VALUES(12345,SenfMeyer)** //WriteLine output of string

```
Stacktrace ist :    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Fehlercode ist : 0
**Fehlername ist : Unknown column 'SenfMeyer' in 'field list'**

**Even funnier, when i replace the Values with the ColumnName, it writes "NULL" in my Database**

As you can see the Program thinks that my Values are the Columnnames, does anybode got an idea why this is happening?

Comment: This is no Business Database or something, just something private for me with local Database and no connection to the internet, so i can use plaintext commands with no fear of Injections or something like this

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is no switching going on. Just as you wrap literal text in double-quotes in C#, so you use single-quotes in SQL. Anything not wrapped in single-quotes is not considered literal text.

```cs
string dataString = $"INSERT INTO kontakte (ID, Name) VALUES ({client.ID}, '{client.Name}')";
```

This is one reason you don't use string concatenation to build SQL code. If you use parameters then there is no literal text, so you can't get that wrong. That's beyond the scope of this specific question though, so you should research that independently.

Comment: Thank you very much! This one helped me :) ! I would like to upvote you answer, but it says that i can´t do this till i got more Reps, sorry "^^

Comment: Perhaps it helped, but you have just postponed the next problem. What happens if a contact has a Name containing an apostrophe? Like _O'Brian_. Try it. So, even if you are not concerned by Sql Injection, you should not use this answer. It just move a bit farther in time when you will discover the wrongness of string concatenation.